# Directory with a number of files and subdirectories: I need to move those files into each subdirectories,as per file name in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have one directory with a number of files and subdirectories. I need to move those files into each subdirectories, depending on their naming. For instance:

Files:

```
Hello.doc
Hello.txt
Hello.xls
This_is_a_test.doc
This_is_a_test.txt
This_is_a_test.xls
Another_file_to_move.ppt
Another_file_to_move.indd
```

Subdirectories:

```
Folder 01 - Hello
Folder 02 - This_is_a_test
Folder 03 - Another_file_to_move
```

What I need is to move the three files named `Hello` into folder `Folder 01 - Hello`; the three files called `This_is_a_test` into directory `Folder 02 - This_is_a_test` and the two files named `Another_file_to_move` into directory called `Folder 03 - Another_file_to_move`. I have hundreds of files, not just these ones.

As it can be seen, the folder name contain the name of the file at the end, but at the beginning there is a `Folder` + `\s` + a `number` + `\s` + a `-`. This is a global pattern.

Any help?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sure. I've used many times `FileUtils` for copying files, moving, renaming, etc. What I can really get is how to tell Ruby to focus on files names, I thought about a regex but I'm lacking the comparative part between file and folder names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rush, try to solve your problem step by step. I would solve your problem in the following steps:

**1. Separate files from subdirectories**

```
subdirectories, files = Dir['/path/to/the/directory/*'].partition{|path| File.directory?(path)}
# TODO ...
```

**2. Iterate over the files and retrieve the basename of each file, without extension**

```
subdirectories, files = Dir['/path/to/the/directory/*'].partition{|path| File.directory?(path)}

files.each do |file|
  basename = File.basename(file, '.*')
  # TODO ...
end
```

**3. Find the subdirectory that the file should go to**

```
subdirectories, files = Dir['/path/to/the/directory/*'].partition{|path| File.directory?(path)}

files.each do |file|
  basename = File.basename(file, '.*')
  subdirectory = subdirectories.find {|d| File.basename(d) =~ /^Folder \d+ - #{Regexp.escape(basename)}$/}
  # TODO ...
end
```

**4. Move the file into that directory**

```
require 'fileutils'

subdirectories, files = Dir['/path/to/the/directory/*'].partition{|path| File.directory?(path)}

files.each do |file|
  basename = File.basename(file, '.*')
  subdirectory = subdirectories.find {|d| File.basename(d) =~ /^Folder \d+ - #{Regexp.escape(basename)}$/}
  FileUtils.mv(file, subdirectory + '/')
end
```

Done. But finding subdirectories using regexp is expensive and we don't want to do this for each file. Can you optimize it?

HINT 1: Trade memory for time.
HINT 2: Hash.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for explanation. I will make my try for optimizing it :)

Answer (score 0):

And here is a faster but not cross-platform solution (assuming your working directory is the directory containing the files and subdirectories), and the code is a little bit chaotic:

```
subdirectories = `ls -d ./*/`.lines.each(&:chomp!)

subdirectories.each do |dir|
  basename = dir =~ /\bFolder \d+ - (\w+)\/$/ && $1
  next unless basename
  `mv ./#{basename}.* #{dir}`
end
```